# How are bit fields sorted for an index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index

I am building a compound index, and I'm not 100% sure which way to include a `bit` field that is part of the table. The index will be for something similar to a list of forum topics, where I want the single index to be by `ForumId` (int), `IsSticky` (bit), then `DatePosted (desc)` (datetime2(0))

But I want to make sure I handle the `IsSticky` bit field properly; Do I index it as if `true` is `1` or `-1`? If it's 1, I would index IsSticky descending; if -1, I would index it ascending.

Also, I'm asking for SQL 2008, but I'd be interested in knowing if it's different in 2005.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A [SQL Server bit field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) can be 0, 1 or NULL, so I'm unsure where the -1 part of your question features.

Skipping past that, the most appropriate solution for "sticky threads" in a forum database is to use a separate [filtered index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx). Flag a sticky thread as `IsSticky=1` and create a filtered index along the lines of:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Posts_StickyThread
    ON dbo.Posts (ForumId, PostId)
WHERE IsSticky = 1;
```

Filtered indexes were new to SQL2008 so this wouldn't be an option for SQL2005. The SQLCat article *Using a Low-Selectivity BIT Column First Can Be the Best Strategy* would be applicable reading for an approach to this in 2005 (edit: article has been archived to the eBook [SQLCAT's Guide to Relational Engine](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/F/B/0FBFAA46-2BFD-478F-8E56-7BF3C672DF9D/SQLCAT%27s%20Guide%20to%20Relational%20Engine.pdf)).

And just to address the title question bit fields in an index are ordered same as per ORDER BY bit_field i.e. NULL, 0, 1 (credit @MartinSmith).

Comment: Mark, question for you.  The only benefit of using a filtered index is purely to save space, right?  I mean, performance wise this would be similar to `create nonclustered index IX_indexname on dbo.Posts (ForumId, PostId)`.  Is that a correct statement?

Comment: Yes and no. Sure, you're only saving a few bytes in a case like this and the performance benefit is going to be difficult to distinguish from a regular non-filtered index. Transpose the situation to something StackOverflow scale however and that benefit might matter. The feature is there, might as well make use of it.

Comment: Great explanation, and great answer.  +1 for both your answer and your comment.

Comment: @Shark - filtered indexes can be a lot faster as well.  If the engine recognizes that the filter matches the filter in a query, you skip an evaluation.

Comment: @JNK I see your point. Instead of having to evaluate non-inclusive records, the filtered index already has done the grunt work. Great information, JNK, thank you!!

Comment: And just to address the title question `bit` fields in an index are ordered same as per `ORDER BY bit_field`. i.e. `NULL,0,1`